# Can React add new Modules asynchronously without recompiling the app?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, webpack

Here is my using case: I built an App Center App using React. Users can search specific apps; they can add an app to their dashboard by clicking the icon of the app(a module consists some js files and CSS files will be downloaded from the server and added to the config file). Then on the dashboard page, the app can be launched after the user click its icon(the module files downloaded will be loaded).

When a new app is added and launched, a brand new module is added to the react app and needs to be loaded. The App Center App cannot be recompiled during this process and the new app should be loaded smoothly. Can somebody give me some advice how I can do this?

Comment: You will rebundle your source files and it will replace the existing bundled script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your using webpack.

If you create seperate chunks for each of your apps you can use a dynamic import, which can load the app asynchronously

```
const _ = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "lodash" */ 'lodash');
```

[Webpack Dyanmic Imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. I will give that a try as soon as possible. Before I test it myself, I have a question: In my App Center App, webpack doesn't know what should be compiled and created as some new apps would be installed by the user when the App center is running. Can dynamic imports of webpack handle this kind of situation? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. I will give that a try as soon as possible. Before I test it myself, I have a question: In my App Center App, webpack doesn't know what should be compiled and created as some new apps would be installed by the user when the App center is running. Can dynamic imports of webpack handle this kind of situation? My goal is to load new modules without calling the webpack to compile again. Thanks again.

Comment: It may not work for that case, Sounds like you need a way for these apps to register themselves with the center, and use that as a key to load and config the app for runtime.

Comment: Hi Nath, you're right, this is a complex problem and with barely webpack I cannot solve the problem. This experimental process took me 10 days and produced no result. If you have any possible solutions, could you please share with me? Thanks very much.